# Can Intellij IDEA navigate from cucumber feature file to file from resources mentioned in step?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

My input data for cucumber tests is big enough, so I moved that to external files in resources.

So my feature file looks like:

```
Given I have a file located at "classpath:example.txt"
When read the file
Then ...
```

Any change IDEA can understand that my argument is a reference to file and help me to navigate to it?

Comment: Unfortunately  IntelliJ IDEA, or any other JetBrains product, does not have native support to resolve any file path from within a Gherkin (Cucumber) feature file and can provide navigation to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in IntelliJ that may help you, although I'm not sure if it's supported on Cucumber files. Try it out by putting your cursor in the string, then selecting the action (Ctrl-shift-A in my keymap): "Inject language or reference", and selecting "File reference":

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but looks like this is not supported for cucumber file

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You could always try writing your own IntelliJ plugin ;-)